# Django Celery throwing runtime warnings for naive times

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, kombu

I run an online game with Django 1.6 and Celery 3.1.11. Kombu is 3.0.15.

Recently I had problems with Celery and DST, so I decided to run the whole site on UTC and save myself the bother of worrying about timezones.

The relevant parts of my settings.py:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_TZ = True
....
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

Now, whenever I send *any* delayed task, I see a bunch of RuntimeWarnings that complain about naive datetimes. I went into my settings.py and turned this into an exception, and this is the traceback that resulted:

```
[2014-04-18 15:03:49,748: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: sometask[sometaskid] eta:[2014-04-19 00:33:32.410032+00:00]
[2014-04-18 15:03:50,130: ERROR/MainProcess] Error in timer: RuntimeWarning(u'DateTimeField TaskState.eta received a naive datetime (2014-04-18 17:50:19.547046) while time zone support is active.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/async/timer.py", line 171, in apply_entry
entry()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/async/timer.py", line 64, in __call__
return self.fun(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kombu/async/timer.py", line 132, in _reschedules
return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/events/snapshot.py", line 73, in capture
self.state.freeze_while(self.shutter, clear_after=self.clear_after)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/events/state.py", line 421, in freeze_while
return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/events/snapshot.py", line 70, in shutter
self.on_shutter(self.state)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 145, in on_shutter
_handle_tasks()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 139, in _handle_tasks
self.handle_task(task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 105, in handle_task
task_id=uuid, defaults=defaults)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/snapshot.py", line 128, in update_task
obj.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/djcelery/models.py", line 358, in save
super(TaskState, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 635, in _save_table
forced_update)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 679, in _do_update
return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 507, in _update
return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 975, in execute_sql
cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 771, in execute_sql
sql, params = self.as_sql()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 940, in as_sql
val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 353, in get_db_prep_save
prepared=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 914, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 906, in get_prep_value
RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField TaskState.eta received a naive datetime (2014-04-18 17:50:19.547046) while time zone support is active.
```

As you can see, none of the traceback is due to my code, so I do not know how to proceed. I could merely leave the warnings in (if I recall correctly, Celery defaults time offsets to the `CELERY_TIMEZONE` in settings.py, and this is what I want anyway) but my OCD is screaming out at me to get this fixed. Plus, I can't ctrl-F to find any warning that *are* due to my code.

Any advice?

Comment: Hi, have you fixed this problem cause I am stuck on it too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: How-to convert naive datetime when time zone support is active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194370/django-how-to-convert-naive-datetime-when-time-zone-support-is-active)